# how to draw horizontal line in y axis in d3 column chart?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, line, angular6

I have a d3 column chart in my angular 6 app and I want to draw lines in y-axis for each label in the y-axis.  I want the lines to be like this:

[image]

I don't know how to draw those light gray lines!

here is my codes from d3:

```
createChart() {
const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
this.width = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
this.height = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
const svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
  .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
  .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);

// chart plot area
this.chart = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'bars')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);

// define X & Y domains
const xDomain = this.data.map(d => d[0]);
const yDomain = [10000, d3.max(this.data, d => d[1])];

// create scales
this.xScale = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.6).domain(xDomain).rangeRound([0, this.width]);
this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(yDomain).range([this.height, 0]);

// bar colors
this.colors = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, this.data.length]).range(<any[]>['#00a0e9', '#00a0e9']);

// x & y axis
this.xAxis = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-x')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top + this.height})`)
  .attr("stroke", "#777777")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale));
this.yAxis = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-y')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
  .attr("stroke", "#777777")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));
}
```

** **Update =>**

I added new configuration below y-axis, it works a little good but the thickness of the lines are not equal, and the other problem is that I have values of 120000 & 122000 as two maximum y but the chart draw line for both of them. it should draw only for 120000

```
this.yAxis = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-y')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
  .attr("stroke", "#777777")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.1)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale)
          .tickSize(-this.width)
          .tickFormat("")

  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I once found this snippet: Draw a second version of the y-axis

```
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
              .tickSize(-width)
              .tickFormat("")
      );
```

And you need a little CSS to style the lines

```
.grid line {stroke: lightgrey;stroke-opacity: 0.7;shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
.grid path {stroke-width: 0;}
```

If you only want the grid lines but not the axis you can use [axis.tickSizeInner([size])](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSizeInner)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I have new problems and I updated my post. can you help me?

Comment: the 122000 line is an outer-tick line, read the axis doc to see what to do to not draw outer-ticks